# Convert and run Python package as .egg file

Tags: python, setup.py, egg

I tried to convert the [langdetect](https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect) package into an .egg file. However, when importing and using the .egg file within python code I get the following error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/workspace/langdetect-1.0.1/dist/langdetect-1.0.1-py2.7.egg/langdetect/utils/messages.properties'
```

After digging into the library code I found that it tries to load the `messages.properties` file as:

```
MESSAGES_FILENAME = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'messages.properties')
with open(self.MESSAGES_FILENAME, 'r') as f:
```

Which obviously does not work when the library is zipped as .egg file since the new path of the `messages.properties` is:

```
/workspace/langdetect-1.0.1/dist/langdetect-1.0.1-py2.7.egg/langdetect/utils/messages.properties
```

How can I change the above code so that the `messages.properties` is loaded from within the .egg file?

Comment: If possible, consider switching to `.whl` files as `.egg` files are outdated.

Comment: I've already tried that, but I ran into the same issue since .whl is also a zip format!